# How to run WorkManager's work retry every 5 seconds

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-workmanager

How to retry work with every 5 seconds?
And if was successful then cancel it?

With the solution below it runs every 10 seconds + Linear growth of time.

```
// todo: schedule, and invoke worker every 5 seconds
// todo: if the work is done and there is no more work in queue - cancel worker.

fun scheduleBatchUpload(uniqueWorkName: String) {
    val logBuilder = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(StreamLogWorker::class.java, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    logBuilder.setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // Custom retry not working

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(uniqueWorkName, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, logBuilder.build())
}


class StreamLogWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!", "doWork")
        return Result.retry()
    }
}
```

Comment: [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/WorkRequest.Builder.html#setbackoffcriteria) claims that **backoffDelay will be clamped between WorkRequest#MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS and WorkRequest#MAX_BACKOFF_MILLIS**. [MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/WorkRequest.html#MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS:kotlin.Long) is exactly 10 seconds. So I think it's not possible to have 5-sec retry period.

Comment: @art yeah, maybe there is other official way to run periodic job with this interval?
Or it is totally impossible to do it because interval is small.
And maybe there is a way to remove BackoffPolicty linear growth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible with the `PeriodicWorkRequest`. if you look at [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder) of the the `PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder` constructor that you are using, you will see that it says following about the second parameter

> The repeat interval must be greater than or equal to
>   PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS.

And the value of `PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS` is 900000, meaning it is equal to 15 minutes.

Comment: And If I want not to "schedule" it every 5 seconds, but to "retry" it every 5 seconds if the work inside fails?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to schedule your task manually, perhaps it can help to reach your goal.

```
private fun WorkManager.launchFrequentTask() {
    val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<StreamLogWorker>()
            .setInitialDelay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
    enqueueUniqueWork(UNIQUE_WORK_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, request)
}

class StreamLogWorker(private val context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        try {
            // TODO doWork
        } catch (th: Throwable) {
            // log error
        }
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).launchFrequentTask()
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Not sure if this really works as you want (every 5 seconds), it is necessary to check.

Comment: Did you checked this solution?

Answer (score 1):

The repeat interval must be greater than or equal to PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS(see documentation).
Periodic work has a minimum interval of 15 minute